# Run a function after control returns to the command loop

Tags: elisp, hooks

Is there a hook that would run as soon as control returns to the user (i.e. to the command loop)?

Context: I'd like to register a function to run as soon as all functions in the current sequence of recursive calls have exited. The call stack looks like 
`... -> a -> b -> ... -> my function`, and I would like my function to run when all functions on the stack have exited.

More context: Somewhere up in the call chain to `my function` there is a function `f` that is ill-behaved, insofar as I can't call it from one of its children (it needs to do some cleanup before I can call it again). Since I can't call `f` from `my function`, I'd like to register the call to `f` to run as soon as `f` has completed.

Comment: The most common hook that runs **after** the current function is the `post-command-hook` -- there is at least one other hook that runs later in time, but not always -- the former always runs exactly one time.  However, this is **before** control returns to the user.  The hook that runs **before** the current function is called the `pre-command-hook`.  Here is a link to the documentation regarding the standard hooks:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run something after the stack clears, run it on a 0 second timer.

```
(run-with-timer 0 nil 'your-function)
```

You could wrap this is a macro like this:

```lisp
(defmacro after-stack-clears (&rest body)
  "Do BODY after the call stack is clear"
  `(run-with-timer 0 nil (lambda () ,@body)))
```

Here's an example usage mimicking your described scenario.

In this example, `annoying-func` is calling another provided function. In the provided function you'd like to call `annoying-func` again but `annoying-func` will error if called more than once on the call stack. So to counter this, the provided macro to ensure that `annoying-func` is called a second time, but only after the call stack has cleared and `annoying-func` has done its cleanup

```lisp
(defun your-func-simple ()
  "try to directly call `annoying-func'."
  (annoying-func (lambda () (message "hi"))))

(defun your-func-smart ()
  "ensure `annoying-func' is called after the stack clears."
  (after-stack-clears
   (annoying-func (lambda () (message "hi")))))

(setq annoying-var nil)

(defun annoying-func (func)
  "This function will apply FUNC, if `annoying-function' is called
somewhere down the line by FUNC, the second call will error, because this 
is the annoying function after all."
  (if annoying-var
      (error "Can't call recursively!")
    (condition-case err
        (progn (setq annoying-var t)
               (apply func nil)
               (setq annoying-var nil))
      (error (progn (message "errored! %s" err) (setq annoying-var nil))))))


(defun erroring-example ()
  (annoying-func 'your-func-simple))

(defun working-example ()
  (annoying-func 'your-func-smart))

;; will error due to annoying-func being called twice on the stack
(erroring-example) 

;; will NOT error since annoying-func is called again only after the stack has cleared
(working-example)
```

Comment: Just keep in mind there can be subtle issues with keymaps and timers: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-pretest-bug/2007-04/msg00279.html

Comment: There are definitely additional concerns one must note with timers, but I'm not sure that bug is still relevant, it is from 2007 and I can't replicate it on Emacs 25.

Comment: I still see the bug in 24.3. By the way, I had also up-voted your answer.

Comment: Ah, well 24.3 is still used by many so good to know, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

As lawlist says, you can use `post-command-hook` for that.

But another option might be to add an advice to the offending function.  Along the lines of:

```
(advice-add 'f :after
            (lambda (&rest args)
              <do-something-after-f-runs>))
```

Comment: Does advising work if the function  is already executing?

Comment: No, you want to advise once and for all from your ~/.emacs, or from the top-level of your package.